Can not open the zip file that zipped by C#
I'm writing a web app ,it can upload/download files, here is my code about download files(just for test):
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now:yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss}.zip";
        var folder = "D:\\xxdd";
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
        
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        File.WriteAllBytes(zipName,memoryStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }

when I opened the zip file, it said the zip is empty, then I dragged it into the bandizip,it said the file was broken,but all the files were in the list and it could be unzip.
how to fix it ?



You don't call Dispose on the ZipArchive, so the data isn't completely written. As the documentation says:
"This method finishes writing the archive and releases all resources used by the ZipArchive object."
I've modified your code example to show one way to do it:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now:yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss}.zip";
    var folder = "D:\\xxdd";
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)}
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    File.WriteAllBytes(zipName,memoryStream.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}

This uses the other (the "old") form of the using statement, which calls Dispose at the end of the using block. The form that you used in your code calls Dispose at the end of the function.

Try this,
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now:yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss}.zip";
    var folder = "D:\\xxdd";
    
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(zipName))
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}


Put the ZipArchive in a separate using block to ensure it's properly
disposed before writing.
The ZipArchive needs to be disposed to finalize the ZIP file
structure.
After disposal, the memoryStream contains the complete ZIP file
data.


Your code is writing to the file system. The OP doesn't want that (given they are using MemoryStream).

this is by @mjwills
it works.
var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now:yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss}.zip";
        var folder = "D:\\xxdd";
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(zipName, memoryStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


I solved the problem,thx
so here is my code , just added a line.
but I still don't know why the using not working.
var zipName = $"archive-{DateTime.Now:yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss}.zip";
        var folder = "D:\\xxdd";
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
        
        //dispose
        zipArchive.Dispose();
        
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        File.WriteAllBytes(zipName,memoryStream.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

